# Times New Roman font with TeXnicCenter

Tags: fonts, times

I'm new to LaTeX and trying to write my rapport with TeXnicCenter. I want to use the times new roman font, but i don't know why it does not works with me.

This the beginning of my code :

```
\documentclass[12pt,french]{report}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2cm,bmargin=2cm,lmargin=3cm,rmargin=3cm}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setlength{\parskip}{\smallskipamount}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{nomencl}
% the following is useful when we have the old nomencl.sty package
\providecommand{\printnomenclature}{\printglossary}
\providecommand{\makenomenclature}{\makeglossary}
\makenomenclature
\onehalfspacing

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{t1enc}% un second package
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
% un troisième package
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{lettrine} 

\floatstyle{boxed}
\title{Rapport de Projet De Fin D'Études}
\author{Amina GHABRI}
\usepackage{palatino}%police
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

\AtBeginDocument{
  \def\labelitemi{\normalfont\bfseries{--}}
}



\usepackage{babel}


\addto\extrasfrench{%
   \providecommand{\og}{\leavevmode\flqq~}%
   \providecommand{\fg}{\ifdim\lastskip>\z@\unskip\fi~\frqq}%
}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\ }
\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[RE,LO]{\ }

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}




\usepackage{babel}

\addto\extrasfrench{%
   \providecommand{\og}{\leavevmode\flqq~}%
   \providecommand{\fg}{\ifdim\lastskip>\z@\unskip\fi~\frqq}%
}




\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\makeatletter
\addto\extrasfrench{%
   \providecommand{\og}{\leavevmode\flqq~}%
   \providecommand{\fg}{\ifdim\lastskip>\z@\unskip\fi~\frqq}%
}
\rmfamily
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\maketitle 
\dominitoc\tableofcontents{}\listoffigures

\listoftables

\chapter{Présenation du projet}
\label{sec:PrésenationDuProjet}
```

And this is what i'm getting :

[image]

Comment: Are you running `lualatex`?

Comment: Your example isn't complete which doesn't really help anyone to gelp you but you appear to be using lualatex given you have `\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}` in which case you probably shouldn't be using luainputenc at all but just using luatex's native utf-8 support and accessing your system times roman font using `fontspec` package.

Comment: Sorry i'm new. well i'm using latex ,miktex and textniccenter.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle i edited the code ,please take a look .

Comment: You have specified `\usepackage{times}` but then later you over-write the font definitions and specify Palatino:
`\usepackage{palatino}%police` presumably you want to remove that line if you want Times

Comment: As well as loading babel three times you define this twice `\addto\extrasfrench{%\providecommand{\og}{`  Your preamble looks like it has been cut and pasted from multiple documents, I would start off by removing it _all_ and using a standard latex report settings, and then just add the definitions or packages that you actually need, as you find you need them.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yess Thank youuu ,it worked, you can put it as an answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have specified

```
\usepackage{times}
```

but then later you over-write the font definitions and specify Palatino:

```
\usepackage{palatino}%police
```

presumably you want to remove that line if you want Times

As you are using pdflatex also change

```
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}
```

to

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are running `pdflatex` use

```
\documentclass[12pt,french]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
...
```

If you are running `lualatex` use

```
\documentclass[12pt,french]{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
...
```

and do *not* load package `t1enc`. The Font name "Times New Roman" may be different depending to your operating system.

However, your preamble looks a bit weird. A package can only be loaded once, `babel`, for example, appears three times in your preamble.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I think i'm using pdflatex, because when i tryed the second code ,i got errors. But when i used the firs code ,i didn't remark any deiference .

Comment: In the first example the font "NimbusRoman" is used which is the same as Times Roman.

Comment: @Amina if you are using pdflatex then you must get error messages on _your_ example document from `\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}`